# How to find the root cause from App Store crash log after symbolicated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I have trouble when received crash log from App Store. The crash log show that EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY crash.

After I symbolicated the crash log file, I have no idea how to further proceed my troubleshooting. I keep trying to test on my own devices but its did not encountered any crash (both are IOS 12).

As below is my crash log:-

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020055d104 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002005d80e0 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000002004b4d78 abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ffb7cf78 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ffb7d120 default_unexpected_handler+ 8480 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ffb95e48 _objc_terminate+ 28232 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ffb890fc std::__terminate(void (*)+ 57596 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ffb88cec __cxa_rethrow + 144
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ffb95c10 objc_exception_rethrow + 44
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000200950624 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000202bc4584 GSEventRunModal + 100
11  UIKitCore                       0x000000022cfcb558 UIApplicationMain + 212
12  MyAPP                           0x0000000100510584 main + 1131908 (main.m:13)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000200410b94 start + 4
```

**Edited**

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2009c7ef8 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ffb95a40 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2008dfdcc -[NSException raise] + 11
3   Foundation                      0x2013d3e54 -[NSObject+ 622164 (NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 247
4   Foundation                      0x201347650 -[NSObject+ 46672 (NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 267
5   Jasiez                          0x1004114f8 -[Map_ViewController viewDidLoad] + 87288 (Map_ViewController.m:303)
6   UIKitCore                       0x22d68de4c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 999
7   UIKitCore                       0x22d28f750 -[UINavigationController _updateScrollViewFromViewController:toViewController:] + 75
8   UIKitCore                       0x22d28fa58 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 171
9   UIKitCore                       0x22d2909e8 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 1183
10  UIKitCore                       0x22d291ce8 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 163
11  UIKitCore                       0x22d223e30 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 223
12  UIKitCore                       0x22d679998 -[UIView+ 10570136 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1379
13  QuartzCore                      0x204fa9a34 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 183
14  QuartzCore                      0x204fae9c4 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1317316 (CA::Transaction*) + 323
15  QuartzCore                      0x204f0d9d4 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 657876 (CA::Transaction*) + 339
16  QuartzCore                      0x204f3c2f4 CA::Transaction::commit+ 848628 () + 607
17  UIKitCore                       0x22cfe5cfc __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 139
18  CoreFoundation                  0x200956408 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 19
19  CoreFoundation                  0x200955d08 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 271
20  CoreFoundation                  0x200950cfc __CFRunLoopRun + 1059
21  CoreFoundation                  0x2009505b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 435
22  GraphicsServices                0x202bc4584 GSEventRunModal + 99
23  UIKitCore                       0x22cfcb558 UIApplicationMain + 211
24  Jasiez                          0x100510584 main + 1131908 (main.m:13)
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x200410b94 start + 3
```

Please help, appreciated!

Comment: It's crashing at Map_ViewController.m line 303. Post that `viewDidLoad` method and relevant details about what you are doing there and its variables.

Comment: Also, make sure you are testing a clear install of the app. Delete the app from your device and do a clean build and install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to read this [Tech Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html)

The stack trace in the crash log can give you a clue on what your app was doing before it happened.
In your case :

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x2009c7ef8 __exceptionPreprocess + 228
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ffb95a40 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2008dfdcc -[NSException raise] + 11
3   Foundation                      0x2013d3e54 -[NSObject+ 622164 (NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 247
4   Foundation                      0x201347650 -[NSObject+ 46672 (NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 267
5   Jasiez                          0x1004114f8 -[Map_ViewController viewDidLoad] + 87288 (Map_ViewController.m:303)
```

It look like your calling an unknown property in your `[Map_ViewController viewDidLoad]` method. [As Apple Documentation states](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1413457-valueforundefinedkey)

> Invoked by valueForKey: when it finds no property corresponding to a
>   given key.

Those makes me think of problem with an Outlet connection but I can be sure without more context.